# NodeJs : How to send an object of multiple values with delete request from Angular to Nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, angular, api, rest, express

Explanation of my question:

From my Angular2+ app I am calling a delete request to node js backend. in this delete request, I want to send an object having two values. I am doing it by two Methods here are the snippets. But Both Methods either give me empty Object {} or undefined values. Please Guide me How can I solve this problem.

**Method 1: Sending the Object as a payload with delete Request**

```
 DeletSingleImageFromRecentWorkGalleryUrl ="http://localhost:7000/work/deleteRecentWorkSingleImage";
```

Api Request From Angular:

```
 DeleteSingleImageFromRecentWorkGallery(Data) {
     let _RequestedObject = {
       ImageCategory: Data.ImageCategory,
       ImageUrl: Data.ImageUrl
     }
     return this.http.delete(`${this.DeletSingleImageFromRecentWorkGalleryUrl}`,_RequestedObject);
   }
```

In Response from Nodejs Backend I get Empty Object. Here is the snippet of backend

Api  Route

```
      Router.delete('/deleteRecentWorkSingleImage',workController.DeleteSingleImageFromRecentWork);
```

Api Controller

```
 DeleteSingleImageFromRecentWork : async(req,res)=>{
    
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({
        Message:'You have Reached The Delete End Point',
        Data:req.body
    })
}
```

Output: Empty Object {}

**Method 2: Sending the Object with URL with delete Request**

```
 DeletSingleImageFromRecentWorkGalleryUrl ="http://localhost:7000/work/deleteRecentWorkSingleImage/";
```

Api Request From Angular:

```
 DeleteSingleImageFromRecentWorkGallery(Data) {
     let _RequestedObject = {
       ImageCategory: Data.ImageCategory,
       ImageUrl: Data.ImageUrl
     }
     return this.http.delete(`${this.DeletSingleImageFromRecentWorkGalleryUrl}${_RequestedObject}`);
   }
```

In Response from Nodejs Backend I get [object object]
but i cannot access the values as it gives me undefined. Here is the snippet of backend

Api  Route

```
      Router.delete('/deleteRecentWorkSingleImage/:Data',workController.DeleteSingleImageFromRecentWork);
```

Api Controller

```
 DeleteSingleImageFromRecentWork : async(req,res)=>{
    
    console.log(req.params.Data);
    res.json({
        Message:'You have Reached The Delete End Point',
        Data:req.params.Data
    })
}
```

Output : [object Object] and when accessing the key pair value it says undefined

Comment: Please [edit] yur question to show us your angular code that calls your `DeleteSingleImageFromRecentWorkGallery` function.

Comment: It has Angular Snippet

Comment: That's why I use POST for everything (with `{ method : "delete" }` in the payload for instance). POST is the only thing that I find to be working.

Comment: Exactly, GET, no payload; DELETE, no payload. That's also why POST is the only method I use and it does the job for everything.

Comment: Got it bro thanks . Bro can I add you on whats app or linkedin just for instant advises